# Can we store string in enum data type in C++?

Tags: c++, data-structures

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    enum month
    {
         Jan = "Enumeration",
         Feb = "is",
         Mar = "a",
         Apr = "user",
         May = "defined",
         Jun = "datatype",
         Jul = "in",
         Aug = "C/C++",
         Sep = "language",
         Oct = "It",
         Nov = "is",
         Dec = "used"
    };
    month mt = Oct;
    cout<<mt;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: And no, enumerations are only integers.

Comment: Also a little nitpicking: There's no such thing like "C/C++". Please don't use that term. Although they might seem similar, C and C++ are two *very* different languages.

Comment: ...but neither C nor C++ supports anything else as integral types to define `enum` values. FYI: [Enumerations in C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum), [Enumerations in C](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/enum)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can store strings in the enumeration type in C++ based on these conditions:

(1.) The strings are the enumeration constants

(2.) The strings should not be enclosed in quotation marks. They should be written "as is"

Based on your example, this is what you may do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
// Declare the enum type for the months
enum months {January, November};

// List the months
switch(November)
    {
    case January:
     cout << "The first month of the year";
     break;

    case November:
     cout << "The current month when this question was asked and answered.";
     break;

    default:
    cout << "Other months besides January and November";
     break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

To see more examples (code implementation), please review:

(1.) https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/enum

(2.) https://www.chukwuemekasamuel.com/CPlusPlus/cplusplus.html#module5 (Scroll till you see Switch statement)